# How to create NSTextField programmatically?

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode4.2, nstextfield

I want to create `NSTextField` programmatically. I am new to Mac App Development.
Can anyone help me in this ?

Update :
I tried this code

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSView *myView = [[NSView alloc] init];
    NSRect frameRect = NSMakeRect(20,20,100,140);
    NSTextField *myTextField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:frameRect];
    [myView addSubview:myTextField];
}
```

This does nothing. Please correct me if i'm wrong anywhere.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're creating an `NSTextField` OK, but you're not adding it to anywhere visible in the view hierarchy. Your app probably contains one or more `NSWindow` instances; if you want a view to appear in a particular window, you should add it as a subview of that window's content view.

Comment: I was trying for that actually. but i don't know how to add a view in my Window. i mean something like `[[self window] addcontentview:my view]` but can't find way. can you help me please.

Comment: Don't replace content view, unless your want your text field to fill the whole window. Instead, add your text field to the content view (or its subview) like [self.window.contentView addSubview:myTextField].

Comment: I got it..!!
Thank you..!! :)

Answer (score 4):

Creating UI elements programmatically is very simple in Cocoa.

It involves two steps:

1. Create the view and set a frame to it.
2. Add it as a subview to any super view.

Following snippet will you help you understand better.

> ```
> NSRect frameRect = NSMakeRect(20,20,40,40); // This will change based on the size you need
>
> NSTextField *myTextField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:frameRect];
>
> [myView addSubview:myTextField];
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Can you help me li'l bit more. I have updated my question. please take a look.